# Combining two lists to make a unique list (based on certain field logic)

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I have a specific problem I am trying to solve, and need some assistance with.

I have a POJO with three fields:

- ID
- Date
- Weighted Number

This POJO can be populated from the DB or an external endpoint and will return a list of said POJO.
Now we end up with two seperate lists with similar infomation. These lists will be unordered and varying in size (sometimes empty).

**How can I combine these two lists to create a single unique list based on the ID?**

- If the IDs are the same, choose the one which has the latest date
- If the IDs and dates are the same, choose the one with the higher weighted number
- If all are the same, it doesn't matter - choose either.

My solution is very cumbersome and ugly to read - it involved two nested loops and 3 pairs of if-else statements. Is there a better way, more efficient way of doing it.

Here is some sample code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Scrap2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyEntity one = new MyEntity("A", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 25), 10);
        MyEntity two = new MyEntity("B", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 25), 10);
        MyEntity three = new MyEntity("C", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 25), 10);
        MyEntity four = new MyEntity("D", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 25), 10);

        List<MyEntity> listOne = Arrays.asList(one, two, three, four);

        MyEntity aaa = new MyEntity("A", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 25), 10);
        MyEntity bbb = new MyEntity("B", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.OCTOBER, 25), 20);
        MyEntity ccc = new MyEntity("D", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 25), 20);
        MyEntity ddd = new MyEntity("E", new Date(2020 - 1900, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 25), 20);

        List<MyEntity> listTwo = Arrays.asList(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd);

        for (MyEntity listItem : combineTwoLists(listOne, listTwo)) {
            System.out.println(listItem);
        }

    }

    private static List<MyEntity> combineTwoLists(List<MyEntity> listOne, List<MyEntity> listTwo) {
       
        return Arrays.asList(listOne.get(0), listTwo.get(1), listOne.get(2), listTwo.get(2), listTwo.get(3));
    }
}


class MyEntity {

    private final String id;
    private final Date date;
   private final Integer weightedNumber;

    public MyEntity(String id, Date date, Integer weightedNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.weightedNumber = weightedNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyEntity{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", date=" + date +
                ", weightedNumber=" + weightedNumber +
                '}';
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public Integer getWeightedNumber() {
        return weightedNumber;
    }
}
```

The output should be something like this (can be unordered/unsorted):

```
MyEntity{id='A', date=Fri Sep 25 2020, weightedNumber=10} 
MyEntity{id='B', date=Sun Oct 25 2020, weightedNumber=20} 
MyEntity{id='C', date=Fri Sep 25 2020, weightedNumber=10} 
MyEntity{id='D', date=Fri Sep 25 2020, weightedNumber=20} 
MyEntity{id='E', date=Fri Sep 25 2020, weightedNumber=20}
```

Comment: Will the order and/or size of the two lists always be the same?

Comment: @JamieBisotti No, the order and size can be different. There might even be cases where one list might be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join both lists first then get the max by date then weightedNumber using `Comparator` with `BinaryOperator.maxBy` for the same id to create a map using `Collectors.toMap`.Then takes the value of the map in new ArrayList.

```
return new ArrayList<MyEntity>(
    Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream())
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyEntity::getId, Function.identity(),
                   BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyEntity::getDate)
                                          .thenComparing(MyEntity::getWeightedNumber))))
          .values());
```

Comment: if the result did not need to be sorted and could be unordered/unsorted. How would your solution change?

Comment: If you don't want to sort what is the default order before merge  the list?

Comment: there is no default order. The lists will either be coming from DB or rest api - and their orders can wildly vary. Sometimes even being empty.

Comment: I mean do you want to maintain any order in list ? if not why you don't want to sort ?

Comment: Oh sorry. There isn't anything wrong with it being sorted apart from the overhead (Im not too familar with streams). The actual entity object I will be applying this solution to will contain about 50 fields and somtimes the lists can have over 500 items in them. Will the overhead in this scenario be neglegible?

Comment: For this dataset sorting wouldn't make any problem, still update the solution without sorting.

Comment: Upvoted for using `BinaryOperator.maxBy` It's a hardly-known, very good utility

Answer (score 2):

The following approach using `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.maxBy` should work:

1. Concatenate the streams of the two lists
2. Group the list by ID using `groupingBy`
3. And then group consequently by `date` and by `weightedNumber` using `maxBy` collector.
4. Convert the resulting map of `Map.Entry<String, Optional<MyEntity>>` to `List<MyEntity>`

```java
private static List<MyEntity> combineTwoLists(List<MyEntity> listOne, List<MyEntity> listTwo) {
    return Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream())
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyEntity::getId,
                          Collectors.maxBy(                                                     
                              Comparator.comparing(MyEntity::getDate)
                                        .thenComparing(MyEntity::getWeightedNumber))
                       )).entrySet() 
                 .stream()  // Stream<String, Optional<MyEntity>>
                 .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // take optional value 
                 .map(Optional::get)       // get from optional
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do this, without streams, yet functional:

```
Map<String, MyEntity> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Consumer<MyEntity> addAction = e -> map.merge(
        e.getId(), 
        e, 
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyEntity::getDate)
                                       .thenComparing(MyEntity::getWeightedNumber)));
listOne.forEach(addAction);
listTwo.forEach(addAction);

List<MyEntity> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

This iterates both lists and executes the `addAction` consumer on each element. The `addAction` consumer consists of *merging* entities in a map, by applying the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method.